# Can't find a way to prevent my regex to match a word in my sql query

Tags: regex

Basicly i want to match a tablename from a sql query. The query can be a joined query or a normal query with where clause. When it's a join i know how to match the table name and its alias. But when it's not a join i just want to find the table name and not match the "where". If there's no where i jsut need the table name aswell.

This is my regex so far : "(?<=FROM|JOIN|ON)(\s+\w+\b.\w+|\s+\w+\b|\s+£\w+\b)(\s+\w+)"

This will match a tablename that's before a from, join or on aswell as its alias.

The one that will select the alias is (\s+\w+) and i want to exclude WHERE from there, i tried [^WHERE] but it has no consequences on the result. And i don't eally know how else i can do that i tried with ?!where but doesn't do anything, it matches only the tablename and where.

```
(?<=FROM|JOIN|ON)(\s+\w+\b\.\w+|\s+\w+\b|\s+£\w+\b)(\s+\w+)
```

This is my current regex.

You can test it here: 
https://regex101.com/r/01hUXM/1/

I'm trying to match "Table T1", "Table T2", "somwhere", "there".

And so far i can match "Table T1" and "Table T2" only. I can't figure out how to match the other two. If i try something like `from\s+(\w+)` It will also match the ones in a join but without the alias and i don't want that.

EDIT:

(?<=FROM|JOIN|ON)(\s+\w+\b.\w+|\s+\w+\b|\s+£\w+\b)(\s+\w+)|from\s(\w+)

This is basicly the idea i want. The first one selects a TableName and an alias and the second one is OR tablename alone (in a group). But for some reason the OR discard the first selection if it can be applied to the result of the first pattern

Comment: Which language are you using? It's important to note since there are different regex engines; each works differently. Btw `[^WHERE]` says to match any character that is not `W`, `H`, `E`, `R`

Comment: I use delphi, but a copy paste from that regex website works perfectly fine, that's why i didn't specify. @ctwheels

Comment: Because Delphi uses PCRE regex library. Make sure you use PHP/PCRE option at regex101.

Comment: A couple of questions regarding your matching in SQL. Why are you trying to get table name after `ON`? That will only get you the relationship, not the table name or its alias. Which database are you using; do you want to catch more obscure table names too like `database name` or `schema name` (e.g. `Production.Table` or `[database].[schema].[table]`)?

Comment: @ctwheels I'm interested in catch "production.table", "tablename" and "£tablename".  I thought the ?< will look before a word, so before the ON that's why. I'm not a regex specialist but i need it now. I'm doing some dynamic stuff that's why i'm trying to extract the tablenames.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @John, what about the `ON` clause? Is that one really needed, cause it's just a relationship.

Comment: @ctwheels No, i removed it and i can still capture the tablename and its alias, works fine without it.

Comment: @John perfect, does [`(?:from|join)\s+(£?\w+(?:\.\w+)?)(?:\s+((?!where)\w+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/01hUXM/2) work for you? I'll post it as an answer if it does.

Comment: @ctwheels Yes it works! thank you man appreciate it. You can post that as answer i'll accept it so you get points or karma idk how it's called here.

Comment: I wonder why you added `ON` to the first group. I also came up with a similar regex some half an hour ago, but so it was matching `ON` and discarded it. See `(?:from|join)\s+\K(£?\w+(?:\.\w+)?)(?:\s+(?!where\b)(\w+))?`, https://regex101.com/r/dSOCve/1. If you need no groups, [this will do](https://regex101.com/r/dSOCve/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex ([see it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/01hUXM/11)) to capture table names and their potential alias immediately following `from` or `join` (with optional database name and schema names preceding the table name). It will also catch your potential case for having a £ prefixing the table's name:

```
(?:from|join)\s+((?:\w+\.){0,2}£?\w+)(?|\s+as\s+(\w+)|\s+(?!where\s+)(\w+))?
```

This shows the basic form for this regular expression (explained below):

- `(?:from|join)` match `from` or `join`
- `\s+` match one or more whitespace characters
- `((?:\w+\.){0,2}£?\w+)` capture the following

  - `(?:\w+\.){0,2}` match the following between zero and two times (this matches `database_name` and/or `schema_name` that might precede the `table_name`)

    - `\w+` matches any word character one or more times
    - `\.` matches `.` literally
  - `£?` optionally matches `£` literally
  - `\w+` matches any word character one or more times (this is the `table_name`)
- `(?|\s+as\s+(\w+)|\s+(?!where\s+)(\w+))?` optionally match either of the following (this is the potential alias). `(?|)` is a branch reset group - this makes each option's capture group the same number (second capture group), without this, option 1's capture group would be numbered 2 and option 3's capture group would be numbered 3.

  - Option 1

    - `\s+as\s+` match any whitespace character one or more times, followed by `as`, followed by any whitespace character one or more times
    - `(\w+)` capture any word character one or more times into the second capture group
  - Option 2

    - `\s+` match any whitespace character one or more times
    - `(?!where\b)` negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not `where` (the second regex below shows how you can expand this to add additional negations)
  - `(\w+)` capture any word character one or more times into the second capture group

Optionally, you may also append `\K` to the regex (see @Wiktor's comment for an example of its usage cutting out everything before the first capture group `from`). It will reset your match to nothing (instead of getting something like `from table t` as a match) - [see `\K` in use here](https://regex101.com/r/01hUXM/12).

[Here's the second regex](https://regex101.com/r/01hUXM/13) with the expanded negation terms to cover mostly everything in MySQL.

```
(?:from|join)\s+((?:\w+\.){0,2}£?\w+)(?|\s+as\s+(\w+)|\s+(?!(?:(?:(?:inner|cross)\s+)?join|(?:natural\s+)?(?:(?:left|right)\s+)?(?:outer\s+)?join|where|(?:group|order)\s+by|having|limit|into|union|on|for\s+update|select)\b)(\w+))?
```